# powershell save download from website without user input

Tags: powershell

I need to download a file from a website every hour .  Right now I have...

```
    $url = "https://www.misoenergy.org/ria/Consolidated.aspx?format=csv" 
    $path = "C:\MISO.csv" 
   # param([string]$url, [string]$path) 

    if(!(Split-Path -parent $path) -or !(Test-Path -pathType Container (Split-Path -parent $path))) { 
      $path = Join-Path $pwd (Split-Path -leaf $path) 
    } 

    "Downloading [$url]`nSaving at [$path]" 
    $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
    $client.DownloadFile($url, $path) 
    #$client.DownloadData($url, $path) 

    $path
    PAUSE
```

This is getting the response from the website and prompting me to open or save the file.  I just want it to save the file.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$url = "https://www.misoenergy.org/ria/Consolidated.aspx?format=csv"
$data = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
$path = "C:\MISO.csv"
$data.content | Out-file $path
```

Of course there is no error handling, or checking. It assumes that Invoke-WebRequest has completed successfully and your endpoint *does* return raw CSV data.

Answer (score 0):

Use wget in my opinion.
The following works for me.

```
 $url = "https://www.misoenergy.org/ria/Consolidated.aspx?format=csv" 
 $path = "d:\my_cs_folder\MISO.csv" 
 wget -OutFile $path -Uri $url
```

I removed the checks for readablity. Destination file Path is changed too. Be advised that you may receive permission denied for placing your file on system drive's root.

Answer (score 0):

I've been attempting a similar thing for a while now and it's very annoying as most cases will not work correctly and sending keystrokes to the save button requires the window to be active, at least for as far as I can see. 
Due to this if the computer is being used it will not work, I still need to figure out a way past this but until now I've gotten it to work like this.

```
$IE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$IE.Visible = $true
$IE.Navigate($url)
$IEProc = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowHandle -eq $IE.HWND}
$WS = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$WS.AppActivate($IEProc.id)
Start-Sleep 2
[Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%{s}')
```

I'm aware of it being very ugly but it does the job :(